# Multithreaded Chatting Program Architecture

Tags: java, multithreading, architecture, software-design, instant-messaging

Currently I am going about making a chatting program (in java for those who are wondering) and I am at the point where I need to come up with a good architecture for the whole thing. This is my current outline, but feel free to provide any feedback (I have no professional training, just some reading).

#### Client Side:

The lifecycle will be as follows:

1. **Connect with the server-** First I plan to have the client establish a connection with the server, prompt the user to login or create a new account, and send these credentials to the server, which will then send back information like the users list of friends and any other relevant data I can think of.
2. **Waiting for the user to connect with someone-** There will be a list of friends who are currently online and that the user can connect with and a button to find and request other users to be friends with them.
3. **Chatting-** I'll go into more detail on the server section, but the user will send text and images to the server which will proceed to rout it to the other user.
4. **Rinse and Repeat-** After the user is done chatting, it will go back to step 2 until they exit out of the program, at which point it will close all connections with the server.

It seems that the client side only needs to be single threaded. Also, if you think of any useful (major) features that many IM type programs have, please share them. I'd be happy to hear (if you want to make me very happy then you could include a general outline for the implementation also :).

#### Server Side

Now this is where it gets rather messy. I think that I am creating way to many threads than I need to. Let me explain.

- The server stores information on each client using a JSON representation of each user. As well, a list of users currently online is maintained.

**Current idea for what chatting looks like server-side:**

1. **Connection established with one client-** The server and client communicate and get the client logged in (or registered), the server tells the client who its friends are, and the client is added to the list of users currently online. As well, at this point I am starting a new thread to listen for input from this client
2. **A client chooses to start a conversation with someone-** At this point I think I need to create a new thread for this conversation, as many of these need to be going on at the same time. As of now my idea is that I start a new thread on the server side which handles all of the routing and comunicated with just those two clients in the conversation.
3. **Wait for more users to connect-** Although I don't ever anticipate more than two people to connect to my server, I would like to make it so that in theory the server can handle multiple conversations. This I believe would be my main thread, waiting for someone to connect then creating a listener thread for them. Once a conversation is set up, this thread would give that conversation its own thread and then go back to what it is doing. This should be able to be done in just one thread (at least according to my logic).

And that's it. Now, of course there are things like graphics and whatnot that I didn't include. Also, with what I have so for in Java I should be able to make conversations between more than two people. Nonetheless, this seems like I am using an excessive amount of threads. There is the main thread, one thread per user, and a thread per conversation. This means that with 1000 users chatting I've started 1501 new threads. Is this excessive? Could I use some type of thread pool? What other suggestions do you have? If I missed anything, just ask (if its something that I haven't thought of then I'll say that too). Finally, if you have any ideas for the actual features of the program, I'd be glad to hear.

Comment: Yes, that is excessive.  Chat is relatively low bandwidth, you should be able to write the server with just one thread.  Clients typically need two threads--one to listen for messages from the server and one for everything else: GUI, sending messages, etc.

Comment: Also, your question is pretty open ended, and not in a good way.  Please read the Help Center FAQ on what kind of questions to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: A simple chat app like that can easily be written with only the standard Java API. You could e.g. use an `ExecutorService` to create a small number of threads and then use `AsynchronousSocketChannel` to allow each thread to handle a large number of concurrent connections.

Answer (score 1):

Neither one thread per conversation or one thread for all conversations is going to scale.  You need something in-between.

Using a thread pool that has some maximum number of allowed threads, for each message received for the conversation, queue up the processing of the message to the thread pool.

As long as there are threads available (i.e., you don't have too many messages to process at once), the message should be processed immediately.

If there are more messages to process than threads in the pool, there will be a delay in processing some messages.  Though this isn't ideal, like the comment said a chat program requires fairly low processing/bandwidth, but managing the maximum size of the thread pool means you're not going to thrash the processor or run out of memory.  Ideal for a scaling solution.

As you increase the hardware size, the number of concurrent threads can increase, though that doesn't sound like it'll be a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use www.netty.io.
there are some tutorials to develop chat client/server : 
http://www.allreadable.com/6b8c8U4g

Comment: The example in that video is not really asynchronous. It uses a while loop that blocks the current thread by reading from the console. That should be avoided if you want to minimize the number of threads you use.